# Mysql exclude entire row if one of the rows in joining table is not matching conditon

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have three tables which are orders, products and orderproducts in which there is a status field in the products table to denote the product is active or inactive. I have to show the orders only if all the products are active. This means if I have an order with two products and one of the products is inactive I have to skip showing that row.

Consider the following example (Status - 1 active, 2 - inactive in product table).

orders

```
+-------------------+
|order_id | column_1|
| 1       | Value 1 |
| 2       | Value 2 |
| 3       | Value 3 |
```

orderproducts

```
+---------------------+
|id | p_id | order_id |
| 1 |  1   |     1    |
| 2 |  2   |     1    |
| 3 |  1   |     2    |
| 4 |  1   |     3    |
```

products

```
+---------------------+
|id |  name  | status |
| 1 | Prod 1 |    1   |
| 3 | Prod 2 |    2   |
```

Desired output

```
+------------+
|  order_id  | 
|      2     | 
|      3     |
```

I tried with joining the tables which didn't help. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: And how do you know if a product is active?

Comment: is active = 1 or 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join`, `group by`, and `having`.  I assume a status of 1 means that the product is active.  So:

```
select p.o_id as order_id
from orderproducts op join
     products p
     on op.p_id = p.id
group by op.o_id
having count(*) = sum(p.status = 1);
```

Note that the `orders` table is not needed, because the order id is in `orderproducts`.

You might be able to write the `having` as:

```
having max(p.status) = 1
```

This assumes that the "active" status is the lowest value available.

Comment: 1 is an active status. I need the orders table as I have to fetch some other columns from the table.

Answer (score 2):

- Assuming that `status = 1` means active.
- Inner Join tables from `order` to `orderproducts` to `products` using appropriate relationships.
- Then, `group by` on the `order_id`, and filter out those orders `having` `Max()` value of status equal to 1.

Try the following:

```
SELECT o.order_id 
FROM orders AS o 
JOIN orderproducts AS op ON op.order_id = o.order_id 
JOIN products AS p ON p.product_id = op.product_id 
GROUP BY o.order_id 
HAVING MAX(p.status) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find orders ids that have at least one non-active product and exclude them from an order list

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE id NOT IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT(orderproducts.order_id)
     FROM orderproducts
     LEFT JOIN products ON orderproducts.p_id = products.id
     WHERE products.status <> 1)
```